# How do I remove SearchYa from Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I recently installed some new software applications and now when I start Internet Explorer I see some custom web search start page called ***SearchYa!***

Whenever I type something in the address bar of Internet Explorer and press Enter it takes me to http://searchya.com/

How do I get rid of this?...

Comment: What should I do?... I don't want to use system restore because I do want to keep the installed software. I only want to get rid of this SearchYa thing.

Comment: I have removed it from Firefox 3.6.28 by going to Tools, Add-ons, Extensions. I selected "searchya.com 1.5.0" and disabled it, then restarted Firefox, then uninstalled it and restarted Firefox again. Firefox is my primary web browser. But I would like to remove it from Internet Explorer as well.

Comment: You mean instead of Google search your browser redirect you there or any web address like `www.somthing.com` also redirect there?

Comment: @avirk The first one - the browser redirects me there instead of Google search. Typing a full website address like www.something.com will get me there, so no problem there. I have checked the search providers by going to Tools, Manage Add-ons, Search Providers and I can see it there but cannot remove it.

Comment: @Sammy please post a screen shot of the add-on.

Comment: @avirk I have managed to remove SearchYa as a search provider in Internet Explorer. I have done so by setting Bing ad default search provider FIRST, and THEN removing SearchYa. I missed that, that's why it didn't want to be removed first, because it was set as default. Although in Firefox I was able to remove SearchYa as search provider, with no need to set the default search provider to something else first. I also removed it from the Extensions list. However I still have this thing in Internet Explorer. I don't think I can post a screen shot here, I would have to answer my own question.

Comment: @Sammy the standard Windows System Restore will not remove everything, you can just jump back to a certain point in time (like before you installed Searchya).

Comment: Yes that's the trick. I will also suggest you to do so. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), there is an area in it that allows you to remove all the stuff Internet Explorer runs on startup.

Comment: OK, so I run autoruns.exe and go to Internet Explorer.

It shows me image path to Java FX, some Microsoft Office, other Microsoft, Oracle, Skype and Adobe DLL files.

There are at least two entries that seem to be relevant here. Ons is called Ironsource LTD Helper Object and the other is called SearchYa Toolbar.

So how do I remove these two? Do I go to the directory path first and delete the associated DLL files and then remove them from registry?

Comment: I have found the two entries in the list of plug-ins in Internet Explorer in add-ons manager. But the status indicates they are inactivated and I can only click to activate them. No option to uninstall.

Comment: Solved! From Autoruns.exe I jumped to c:\program files (x86)\ironsource\searchya\1.5.13.0\bh and deleted searchya.dll. Then I jumped to its registry key and deleted the key. I then jumped to c:\program files (x86)\ironsource\searchya\1.5.13.0 and deleted searchyatlbr.dll. Then I jumped to its registry key and deleted only its value from the Toolbar key. Because this key is shared with other IE toolbars.

Comment: But even after doing this it was still there in Internet Explorer. But there was an uninstall.exe file in its install directory which effectively removed it from the computer. It opened up a website saying that I "have successfully uninstalled the searchya toolbar."

Comment: Now restart the IE then check if it still there.

Comment: At this point I have come to realize that it was gone long before that. What I was seeing was the start page of my IE browser. The toolbar had put http://searchya.com/ as my start page. Lol! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

- First remove SearchYa from "Programs" uninstall in "Control Panel".
- Search for SearchYa in "Start" (left corner) and delete anything with the name SearchYa by right clicking the mouse and deleting it.   This will remove the tool bar.
- In your browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox etc) highlight a new home page URL (example `http://www.google.ca/`), then drag the page to your "Home" (right corner on Firefox left corner on Explorer) button.